# MS SQL Insert into concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, substring, concatenation

I need pick up first character from  Column2_table1 and add it before value from  Column1_table1 and this join value i would like get into emptly column Column3_table1.

I have :

```
Column1_table1   Column2_table1   Column3_table1
1234               abcd              
1245               aeio
1545               dfaf
1545               jhui 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] ([Column3_table1])
SELECT  
    Column1_table1, 
    CONCAT(left(Column2_table1,1) ,Column1_table1)
FROM Table1
```

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 The select list for the INSERT
>   statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of
>   SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

I need

```
Column1_table1   Column2_table1   Column3_table1
1234               abcd              a1234
1245               aeio              a1245
1545               dfaf              d1545
1545               jhui              j1545
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You try to insert two columns from select in one column in insert

Comment: The number of columns in `SELECT` (([Column3_table1])) is 1 whereas those in `INSERT` is 2 (Column1_table1, CONCAT(left(Column2_table1,1) ,Column1_table1)).

Comment: You want UPDATE. However, it's generally a bad idea to store "calculated" values like that. Have a view instead. Or a computed column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] 
SET [Column3_table1] = LEFT(Column2_table1, 1) + Column1_table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem,

```
update `Table1` set `Column3_table1` = CONCAT(left(`Column2_table1`,1) ,`Column1_table1`)
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] SET [dbo].[Table1] ([Column3_table1]) = concat(SUBSTRING ([dbo].[Table1] ([Column2_table1]),1,1),[dbo].[Table1] ([Column1_table1]))
```

hope this help.